# Is it possible to combine 2 attributes in a @Html.LabelFor(Login + Email)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, email, authentication

I want to combine 2 inputs in only 1(Login + Email).
Let say that I want :

- 1 Login/Email Input(to get a Login OR an Email)
- 1 Password Input

Is there any way to do "something like" that?

```html
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.Login +" or "+ m.User.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.Login +" or "+ m.User.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.Login +" or "+ m.User.Email)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.User.Password)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User.Password)
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Sign Up", "SignUp")
}
```

Comment: The thing you are trying to do can be done in a more convenient manner if you add a new column "Username" to the table and enter values in it at the time of registration (Login or Email) and at the time of Login you can use : @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)

Comment: @Jimesh Well yes I guess I have no choice... I was just wondering if there was a way to do it with several columns on the table, but obviously not...